# Hibernate map field of an Entity as a foreign key to multiple Entities

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to save address of User and Employee entities in the Address entity.
How do I design my Address entitiy so that I am able to save address of a User as well as an Employee.

Comment: What do the many JPA docs on the internet tell you to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an abstract base class Person with Address Entity as a member.
2. Extend the Person class in User and Employee sub-classes.

   ```
   @MappedSuperclass
   abstract class Person {
       @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS")
       protected Address address;
   }

   @Entity
   class Employee extends Person {}

   @Entity
   class User extends Person {}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, one is to make the Address Entity embeddable,

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
   ....
}

@Entity
public class User {
     .....
    @Embedded
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
public class Employee {
     .....
    @Embedded
    private Address address;

}
```

This will copy the columns in the table Employee and in the table User.

Another approach is to use the address as a table if you want to share addresses:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
   ....
}

@Entity
public class User {
     .....
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
public class Employee {
     .....
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

}
```

Comment: going by the second method, how is the address entity going to find out that the address is for a User or an Employee.

Comment: Does the address need to know the user or employee?

Comment: yes the address also should have the info about the User/Employee

Comment: Ok, I think that you should go with single table inheritance, and create a single table to store user and employee.

Comment: if not the address table will have two foreing keys, one to user and one to employee. I think that the best should be that the address has only one foreing key